# SharePoint Number Field - Remove Comma Separator

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

My document library in a SharePoint site has reached threshold limit and because of which I am not able to update number field to remove comma separator.

Is there any way either through PowerShell or something to update number field and remove the comma separator?

Updated:
$siteurl = "https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/sites/abcsite"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -Interactive

Set-PnPField -List "DMS_MPC" -Identity "DocumentNumber" -Values @{CommaSeparator=$false}

ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below PnP PowerShell code. It works for normal document library. I was not able to test it for document library reaching threshold limit (I don't have enough documents on test environment).

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<siteName> -UseWebLogin

Set-PnPField -List "Documents" -Identity "NumberCol" -Values @{CommaSeparator=$false}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Set-PnPField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnpfield?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I get the following error when i try PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-PnPField -List "DMS_MPC" -Identity "DocumentNumber" -Values @{CommaSeparator=$false}
Set-PnPField : Unable to retrieve the list specified using the List parameter
Parameter name: List
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PnPField -List "DMS_MPC" -Identity "DocumentNumber" -Values @{Com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-PnPField], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Fields.SetField

Comment: when i try complete sharepoint URL along with site, i get 404 error and when the try with only https://abc-admin.sharepoint.com it returns above error. Please advice

Comment: In `Connect-PnPOnline` command, you have to use URL of site where you created document library. In `Set-PnPField` command, you have to pass the display name of library in `-List` parameter.

Comment: I tried this, its not working. Returns 404 not found.

Comment: Can you add the code you tried to your question & the screenshot of an error message (edit original question)?

Comment: Please check the updated Question

Comment: Do not add `-admin` in site URL. It should be simply like: `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/abcsite`.

Comment: Great Great!! It worked.. Thank you so much Ganesh